# Istio 1.4.7 - Kiali pod fails to start

Tags: istio

After installing the Istio 1.4.7, Kiali pod is not coming up cleanly. Its failing with error - `signing key for login tokens is invalid`

```
kubectl get po -n istio-system | gre kiali
NAME                                      READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
kiali-7ff568c949-v2qmq                    0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   56         4h22m
```

```
kubectl describe po kiali-7ff568c949-v2qmq  -n istio-system
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From                                               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----                                               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  29s                default-scheduler                                  Successfully assigned istio-system/kiali-774d68d9c7-4trpd to ip-10-75-64-5.eu-west-2.compute.internal
  Normal   Pulling    28s                kubelet, ip-10-75-64-5.eu-west-2.compute.internal  Pulling image "quay.io/kiali/kiali:v1.15.2"
  Normal   Pulled     27s                kubelet, ip-10-75-64-5.eu-west-2.compute.internal  Successfully pulled image "quay.io/kiali/kiali:v1.15.2"
  Normal   Created    12s (x3 over 27s)  kubelet, ip-10-75-64-5.eu-west-2.compute.internal  Created container kiali
  Normal   Pulled     12s (x2 over 26s)  kubelet, ip-10-75-64-5.eu-west-2.compute.internal  Container image "quay.io/kiali/kiali:v1.15.2" already present on machine
  Normal   Started    11s (x3 over 26s)  kubelet, ip-10-75-64-5.eu-west-2.compute.internal  Started container kiali
  Warning  BackOff    5s (x5 over 25s)   kubelet, ip-10-75-64-5.eu-west-2.compute.internal  Back-off restarting failed container
```

```
kubectl logs  -n istio-system kiali-7ff568c949-v2qmq 
I0429 21:23:11.024691       1 kiali.go:66] Kiali: Version: v1.15.2, Commit: 718aedca76e612e2f95498d022fab1e116613792
I0429 21:23:11.025039       1 kiali.go:205] Using authentication strategy [login]
F0429 21:23:11.025057       1 kiali.go:83] signing key for login tokens is invalid
```

Comment: Hi, see this issue https://github.com/kiali/kiali/issues/2624 and in particular this comment: https://github.com/kiali/kiali/issues/2624#issuecomment-610527042

Answer (score 0):

As @Joel mentioned in comments

> see this [issue](http://github.com/kiali/kiali/issues/2624) and in particular this [comment](http://github.com/kiali/kiali/issues/2624#issuecomment-610527042)

and mentioned [here](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/23146)

> Istio 1.4.7 release does not contain ISTIO-SECURITY-2020-004 fix
>
> The release notes for Istio 1.4.7 state that the security vulnerability relating to Kiali has been fixed; however, the commit to fix this is not present in the release.

---

As far as I understand from this [comment](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/23146#issuecomment-618077491)  if you use istioctl it should work.

> The istioctl installer was fixed.

**but**

> If you installed with the old helm charts, then it wasn't fixed there. I thought the helm charts were deprecated. In any event, add these two lines to the kiali configmap template in the helm chart:

```
login_token:
  signing_key: {{ randAlphaNum 10 | quote }}
```

---

If that won't work I would recommend to upgrade to istio version 1.5.1, it should fix the issue.

Comment: I manage to solve it by changing the docker image of Kiali from 1.5.1 to 1.4.0 tag